# How does the root React component interact with the rest of the application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a working UI skeleton built using React. There's a root component that contains all of the state information, it has 2 child components: 1 that displays some of the state information (data), and 1 that contains buttons that can alter some of the state information via callbacks. If I initialize it with hard-coded dummy data it all works.

Then I have the actual meat of my application, which does *not* use React or Angular or Redux or anything of the sort, that I need to be able to alter the root component's state in some way (i.e. pass it the raw data to display).

Now, how do I actually couple the React UI with the separate business logic of my application? Or, how do I pass outside data into my root React component?

I'd really, really like to avoid adding more libraries.

Comment: You can access globally declared functions and variables from within your React component. Try creating a getter function for the data you want inside the React component and calling it inside React whenever you want the data, and then setting the state accordingly based on the results of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to have your outside code call

`ReactDOM.render(
  <Root propertyYouWantToUpdate={value} />,
  documentGetElementById('your-root-element')
)`

And inside your root component create a custom

`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
  // calculate new state based on nextProps and existing state...
   this.setState(newCalculatedState)
}`